# Current View Identification

Tags: android, android-layout

There are views like grid view and text views which are in same activity. I want to get the focus to text view from grid view when i press the back button as i need to select another text view. All the text views are put in a linear layout.How is it possible?

Comment: Explain your question clearly..

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will it help?

```
View.getId() == R.id.your_required_view
```

Comment: i need to get back from grid view to textview when i press the return button. How is it possible?

Comment: where are your TextView and GridView are located? in different activities? or in same activities?

Comment: Secondly, If your GridView and TextView are in same Activity, why you have to "return" to it? please edit the question and add more details like which scenario ur using it in

Comment: Android's View class does not have a getId() method.

Comment: It does: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29